# how to remove 'memory' issues in arc project?

Tags: xcode

In my project I am using arc, but I'm still facing memory issue problems.  Can any tell me  how to remove them?

```
-(IBAction)familyHistoryBtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    FamilyHistoryViewController *FamilyViewController=[[FamilyHistoryViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FamilyHistoryViewController" bundle:nil];
    FamilyViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50 , 809, 748);
    FamilyViewController.view.tag=112;
    [self removeSubview:112];

    [self.view addSubview:FamilyViewController.view];
}

-(IBAction)pastMedicalHistoryBtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    MedicalHistoryViewController *medicalViewController=[[MedicalHistoryViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MedicalHistoryViewController" bundle:nil];
    medicalViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50 , 809, 748);
    medicalViewController.view.tag=113;
    [self removeSubview:113];
    [self.view addSubview:medicalViewController.view];

}
```

Comment: What kinds of problems? Are you leaking memory? Or just running out of it?

Comment: i have a view controller with 4 buttons. when i click on each button iam adding a viewcontroller(addsubview)onthat viewcontroller. so simuntaniously cicking on all 4 button after 10-15 times, its showing memory issues and then app is crashing , iam using arc in my project so i cant release them.

Comment: This sounds like you still have live references to each of them. Do you keep a list or something like that? ARC means you don't need to call release, but you should still let go of objects you don't use.

Comment: Can u tell me clearly please

Comment: I can't help you until you give me more details. Specifically, when you create the extra viewcontrollers, what do you assign them to? A local variable?

Comment: i have to pasted my code  in my question can u check it please

Comment: @lance Unfortunate edit clash here? Or do you think my rollback was wrong? I rolled back the previous edit because it added code to a question. It didn't merely change indentation.

Comment: I have no clue. I didn't add the lines, but the edit system thinks I did. @muralikrishna, can you check the question and edit as needed?

Comment: @ChristopheBiocca Ah, a number of simultaneous edits most likely then. The additions might well have come from the OP. (Especially seeing how he is the one accepting the suggested edit)

Comment: then when should i do, can u plz tell me

Comment: @Bart, I was being lax and didn't pay enough attention to the code (because after you do an edit it doesn't take you back to look at things).  You're more than welcome to put that code back if it needs to be.

Comment: ok i pasted this code to get and idea for you what i have wrote.